# Reason for 風が強い vs. 雨だ or 雪だ

Tags: nuances, nouns

Just wondering how nouns like 雨 or 雪 can be used alone to mean 'rainy (weather)' or 'snowy (weather)' respectively, when they already can mean rain or snow, but 風 cannot be used in the same sense to mean 'windy (weather)' and must instead be used in a phrase like

> A: 今日の天気予報は何ですか。
>   B: 今日は風が強い。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like 雨 or 雪 are viewed as weather phenomena, which are more black-and-white (either it rains/snows or it doesn't) whereas wind lies on a continuous spectrum. So to say "windy weather" (which in English also should be understood as "*stronger than usual* wind") in Japanese it seems more common to say 風が強い, meaning that often during the day the wind tends to be towards the "strong" end of the spectrum.

In English, "rainy" or "snowy" can be understood as "raining/snowing *on and off*", (similarly "gusty"). On the other hand, you can't say "haily", presumably because "hailing on and off" is not perceived as a natural weather condition.

Comment: You can also say "it's raining/snowing" but never "it's winding".

Answer (score 0):

I think it's also if you'd say 今日はかぜだ I'd right away interpret it as 今日は風邪だ (the speaker having a cold today), rather than it being a windy day, so it might also be to avoid confusion.